# JAXBException with Python for allure report

Tags: python, java, jenkins, allure

I faced the issue with python project when I ran my test cases via jenkins and expected to see Allure report. On remote server I have Java11 and there is no possible to install lower version.

```
TestJob] $ /var/lib/jenkins/tools/ru.yandex.qatools.allure.jenkins.tools.AllureCommandlineInstallation/allure1/bin/allure generate -c -o /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/SIGMAC_Backend_Tests/TestJob/allure-report
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/JAXBException
at io.qameta.allure.allure1.Allure1Plugin.xmlFiles(Allure1Plugin.java:393)
at io.qameta.allure.allure1.Allure1Plugin.getStreamOfAllure1Results(Allure1Plugin.java:388)
at io.qameta.allure.allure1.Allure1Plugin.readResults(Allure1Plugin.java:103)
at io.qameta.allure.ReportGenerator.lambda$readResults$0(ReportGenerator.java:32)
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)
at io.qameta.allure.ReportGenerator.readResults(ReportGenerator.java:32)
at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195)
at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:177)
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1655)
at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484)
at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
at java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:913)
at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:578)
at io.qameta.allure.ReportGenerator.generate(ReportGenerator.java:54)
at io.qameta.allure.ReportGenerator.generate(ReportGenerator.java:43)
at io.qameta.allure.Commands.generate(Commands.java:88)
at io.qameta.allure.CommandLine.run(CommandLine.java:129)
at java.base/java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:369)
at io.qameta.allure.CommandLine.main(CommandLine.java:72)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
... 20 more
ERROR: Build step failed with exception
ru.yandex.qatools.allure.jenkins.exception.AllurePluginException: Can not generate Allure Report, exit code: 1
at ru.yandex.qatools.allure.jenkins.AllureReportPublisher.generateReport(AllureReportPublisher.java:314)
at ru.yandex.qatools.allure.jenkins.AllureReportPublisher.perform(AllureReportPublisher.java:231)
at jenkins.tasks.SimpleBuildStep.perform(SimpleBuildStep.java:123)
at hudson.tasks.BuildStepCompatibilityLayer.perform(BuildStepCompatibilityLayer.java:81)
at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:21)
at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:808)
at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.performAllBuildSteps(AbstractBuild.java:757)
at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.post2(Build.java:179)
at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.post(AbstractBuild.java:701)
at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1936)
at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:100)
at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:433)
Build step 'Allure Report' marked build as failure
Started calculate disk usage of build
Finished Calculation of disk usage of build in 0 seconds
Started calculate disk usage of workspace
Finished Calculation of disk usage of workspace in 0 seconds
Finished: FAILURE
```

Is there any chance to fix it ?

Comment: Check the permissions on your jaxb jar.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You're gonna need to add the required JAXB dependency on the classpath when running the Python code. Get the required jar and add the path of it to the CLASSPATH environment variable when you run the Python script.

Comment: there is no way to add java dependency to Python.
I have test framework written on Pytnoh. It is on git and I run it via Jenkins on remote server. This issue comes from remote server, because there is Java11 installed

Answer (score 0):

1. Java 11 deleted the JAXB APIs completely.
2. Downgrade you server to Java 8 or run your tests remotely on Docker container with Java 8.
3. Rewrite you frame to Java so you can simply add this deprecated libs in dependency pom.xml.